# How do you disable edge tiling?

Tags: gala, settings, window-manager

Is there a way to disable those sticky edges (where the window resizes when it is moved into the edge of the screen) through command line/dconf editor?

Comment: What do you mean by sticky edges? Which version of elementary OS are you using?

Comment: Actually my issue is a bit more complicated and I was deliberetely trying to keep it simple because I thought the solution would be turning off sticky edges. The problem is multi-monitor setup, in particular a vertical one. To give you more background: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143383/dual-monitors-with-one-above-the-other and https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1600335

Comment: My upper display is larger than the built-in monitor below, but it's like there was an invisible edge in the middle of it corresponding probably to the edge of the built-in monitor. So when moving a window in the upper monitor you "bump" into that invisibe edge. I know it's hard to explain, sorry :)

Comment: Update: Wingpanel seems a key element in this issue. If you kill it, the problem disappears and you can move windows around without impediments.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by sticky edges that windows change their appearance when they are moved close to the edge of the screen (e.g. get maximised), you can indeed disable this in elementary freya 0.3.2. The path within dconf-editor would be:

org - pantheon - desktop - gala - behavior

There you can uncheck the box named edge-tiling.